# fadeIn and fadeOut stops after adding animation to width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu made of div elements when you mouseenter the menu-item it rotates and fades the next div.container nested elements but when i add an animation to the width of the div.container the fadeIn and fadeOut stops it's just rotates them what going with that can somebody change my code so it will work properly i can't figure it out. http://jsfiddle.net/EcgTa/

here is my code

```
function rotateZIndex(currentMenuItem) {
    var $currentContent = $('#' + $(currentMenuItem).attr('class').split(' ')[1]),
    $contentContainer = $currentContent.closest('.container'),
    $contentItems = $('> div', $contentContainer);

   $contentItems.not($currentContent)
   .css('z-index', function (i, val) { return val - 1 })
   .fadeOut();
   $currentContent.css('z-index', $contentItems.length).fadeIn();
}

$('.menu-item').mouseenter(function () {                        
    $(this).closest('.container').next('.container').animate({ width: 200 });
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).closest('.container').next('.container').stop(false, true);
}).mouseover(function() {
    rotateZIndex(this);
});


<div id="container1" class="container" 
    style="width:220px; position:relative; float:left">
    <div class="menu-item menu-1-1">
        <div class="menu-item-middle">
            <a href="#"><span class="header" 
                style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:.95em; font-weight:bold">Technology</span>
            <span class="description" 
                style="font-family:Arial; font-size:.7em; color:#0b83bb">Computers &amp; Office 
            Supplies</span> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item-left">
            <div class="item-corner">
            </div>
            <div class="item-icon">
                <img alt="" height="36" src="images/spacer.gif" width="36" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item-right">
            <img alt="" height="44" src="images/spacer.gif" width="26" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item menu-1-2">
        <div class="menu-item-middle">
            <a href="#"><span class="header" 
                style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:.95em; font-weight:bold">Interests</span>
            <span class="description" 
                style="font-family:Arial; font-size:.7em; color:#0b83bb">Movies Books &amp; 
            Music</span> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item-left">
            <div class="item-corner">
            </div>
            <div class="item-icon">
                <img alt="" height="36" src="images/spacer.gif" width="36" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item-right">
            <img alt="" height="44" src="images/spacer.gif" width="26" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item menu-1-3">
        <div class="menu-item-middle">
            <a href="#"><span class="header" 
                style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:.95em; font-weight:bold">Entertainment</span>
            <span class="description" 
                style="font-family:Arial; font-size:.7em; color:#0b83bb">Sofware &amp; Games</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item-left">
            <div class="item-corner">
            </div>
            <div class="item-icon">
                <img alt="" height="36" src="images/spacer.gif" width="36" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item-right">
            <img alt="" height="44" src="images/spacer.gif" width="26" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item menu-1-4">
        <div class="menu-item-middle">
            <a href="#"><span class="header" 
                style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:.95em; font-weight:bold">Kids</span>
            <span class="description" 
                style="font-family:Arial; font-size:.7em; color:#0b83bb">Toys &amp; Games</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item-left">
            <div class="item-corner">
            </div>
            <div class="item-icon">
                <img alt="" height="36" src="images/spacer.gif" width="36" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item-right">
            <img alt="" height="44" src="images/spacer.gif" width="26" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item menu-1-5">
        <div class="menu-item-middle">
            <a href="#"><span class="header" 
                style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:.95em; font-weight:bold">Clothing</span>
            <span class="description" 
                style="font-family:Arial; font-size:.7em; color:#0b83bb">Shoes Jewelry &amp; 
            Apparel</span> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item-left">
            <div class="item-corner">
            </div>
            <div class="item-icon">
                <img alt="" height="36" src="images/spacer.gif" width="36" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item-right">
            <img alt="" height="44" src="images/spacer.gif" width="26" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item menu-1-6">
        <div class="menu-item-middle">
            <a href="#"><span class="header" 
                style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:.95em; font-weight:bold">Pharmacy</span>
            <span class="description" 
                style="font-family:Arial; font-size:.7em; color:#0b83bb">Health &amp; Beauty</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item-left">
            <div class="item-corner">
            </div>
            <div class="item-icon">
                <img alt="" height="36" src="images/spacer.gif" width="36" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item-right">
            <img alt="" height="44" src="images/spacer.gif" width="26" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item menu-1-7">
        <div class="menu-item-middle">
            <a href="#"><span class="header" 
                style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:.95em; font-weight:bold">Home</span>
            <span class="description" 
                style="font-family:Arial; font-size:.7em; color:#0b83bb">Furniture Outdoors 
            &amp; Garden</span> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item-left">
            <div class="item-corner">
            </div>
            <div class="item-icon">
                <img alt="" height="36" src="images/spacer.gif" width="36" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item-right">
            <img alt="" height="44" src="images/spacer.gif" width="26" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container2" class="container" style="position:relative; float:left">
    <div id="menu-1-1" 
        style="height:300px; margin-left:2px; position:absolute; background-color:Aqua; z-index:0">
        Some Text</div>
    <div id="menu-1-2" 
        style="height:280px; margin-left:2px; position:absolute; background-color:Blue; z-index:1">
        Some Text</div>
    <div id="menu-1-3" 
        style="height:260px; margin-left:2px; position:absolute; background-color:Fuchsia; z-index:2">
        Some Text</div>
    <div id="menu-1-4" 
        style="height:240px; margin-left:2px; position:absolute; background-color:Gray; z-index:3">
        Some Text</div>
    <div id="menu-1-5" 
        style="height:220px; margin-left:2px; position:absolute; background-color:Green; z-index:4">
        Some Text</div>
    <div id="menu-1-6" 
        style="height:200px; margin-left:2px; position:absolute; background-color:Lime; z-index:5">
        Some Text</div>
    <div id="menu-1-7" 
        style="height:180px; margin-left:2px; position:absolute; background-color:Maroon; z-index:6">
        Some Text</div>
</div>

div.menu-item
   {
       padding-left:41px; padding-right: 25px; cursor:hand
   }    
   div.menu-item-left 
   {
       width:41px; height:44px; float:left; position:relative;right:41px; margin-left:-100%
   }
   div.menu-item-left .item-corner 
   {
       width:3px; height:44px; float:left; 
   }
   div.menu-item-left .item-corner.selected
   {
       background:url('images/Menu_Item_Corner.jpg') no-repeat;
   }
   div.menu-item-left .item-icon 
   {
       float:right;
   }
   div.menu-item-left .item-icon.selected
   {
        background:url('images/Menu_Item_Middle.jpg') repeat-x;
   }
   div.menu-item-left .item-icon img
   {
       margin-top:3px; margin-bottom:3px; border:1px solid #969ba0
   }
   div.menu-item-middle 
   {
       width:100%; height:44px; position:relative; float:left
   }
   div.menu-item-middle.selected
   {
       background:url(images/Menu_Item_Middle.jpg) repeat-x;
   }       
   div.menu-item-middle a
   {
       display:block; text-decoration:none; color:#0b83bb
   }
   div.menu-item-middle span.header 
   {
       display:block; margin-top:6px; margin-left:3px
   }
   div.menu-item-middle span.description 
   {
       display:block; margin-left:3px
   }
   div.menu-item-right 
   {
       width:26px; height:44px; float:left; position:relative; margin-right:-26px; background:url(images/Menu_Item_Arrow.jpg) no-repeat;
   }
   div.menu-item-right.selected 
   {
        background:url('images/Menu_Item_Arrow_Over.jpg') no-repeat;
   }
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant parts of your code

Comment: the animation for mouseover causes your element to enter a mouseleave event which triggers the fadein fadeout effect to stop

Comment: so what do i do to fix that. I put rotateZindex function on mouseenter that still didn't work either.

Comment: It doesn't trigger mouseleave, stick an alert in there, you'll see it's not firing.  This is an odd one.

Comment: It worked perfectly on mouseenter but as soon as i added the animation to .container (animating the width) the fadeIn fadeOut stopped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
.container{
 overflow: visible !important   
}
```

EDIT: a bit more research turned up this explanation:

Apparently when you animate the width, jquery sets the overlow of the item to hidden.  This forces it to stay visible.

Similar to this:  [JQuery: Children Disappear on Parent Size Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411506/jquery-children-disappear-on-parent-size-animation)

Comment: thankyou that work but I want to hide those elements nested inside .container element so there widths are outside the box to the left cos I want to animate the left property from -200 to 0

Comment: I guess I have to add or wrap a parent element to hide the .container element then