# Overlapping div with jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I am increasing and decreasizing the size of a "row" with jquery `animate()`. Sometimes there is a badge on that row. Now its quite ugly how the badge gets hidden during the animation. Already tried lots of things and also z-index etc. But don't know to fix this. The "badge" should just stay there without hiding.

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0u6gsjn/5/)

Any suggestion?

Comment: Just to clear something up. The other div isn't overlapping the badge. The second div that contains the image div is being set to overflow:hidden during the animation. Anything outside the bounds of the div will not be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution requires you to move the badge div in to the first div. Hope that's OK?

```
<div style="width:100%;height:50px;border: 1px solid red;background:grey;">

    <div style="left: -moz-calc(100% - 90px); left: -webkit-calc(100% - 90px); left: calc(100% - 90px); top:25px; width:100px; height:50px; position:relative; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; background-image:url('http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/winner-badge-81762.jpg');"></div>

</div>

<div id="openrow" style="width:100%; height:50px; border: 1px solid red; background:red;">
</div>

<button onclick="start();">Start</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u0u6gsjn/12/

Comment: great thought. Never thought about it . Have to rework my function a bit but I think this does the trick thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1: (Not favourable) Change to abs positioning.**

If you change the positioning of the image div to absolute, it no longer causes it to fall behind the top div.

https://jsfiddle.net/u0u6gsjn/10/

`<div style="left: -moz-calc(100% - 90px); left: -webkit-calc(100% - 90px); left: calc(100% - 90px); top:30px; width:100px; height:50px; position:absolute; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; background-image:url('http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/winner-badge-81762.jpg');"></div>`

**Solution 2**

Set the child overflow to `overflow: visible !important` answer was found in similar thread discussing problem.

[JQuery: Children Disappear on Parent Size Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411506/jquery-children-disappear-on-parent-size-animation)

Comment: It looks like this works, but you cheated a bit. The image div is no longer relative to its container. You also had to change the image div top attribute to 30px, but this is 30px from the top of the document.

Comment: sorry I can not accept because I definetely need relative as I am creating a lot of rows and this does not work.

Comment: According to another similar question during animation the overflow of the parent is set to hidden which is causing this. 

You can force it to display by setting `overflow: visible !important` on the child element. Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u0u6gsjn/16/. 

Here is a similar thread: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411506/jquery-children-disappear-on-parent-size-animation

Comment: Solution 2 does not the trick because in fiddle /16 you also have the "badge" in the first div as the current accepted answer. and tried if this overflow: visible important! does work if "badge" is on the 2nd div but it does unfortunately not for me. if this would have worked would be great because than i only have to add one css line instead of rework my complete function